# LibGDX's ShapeRenderer: Why am I getting strange lines in the rendering?

Tags: java, libgdx, gradient

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/656x519q90/673/RydRMp.png]

I have searched here on StackOverflow and saw that the `ShapeRenderer` has some issues under some circumstances, but could not find a problem similar to my own. I have tried the solutions for other problems, but to no avail.

I thought that maybe it was the noise library that I made, but then I tried using ANL's Java port and it gets the exact same problems. Rarely if I drag the screen size around I can get the lines to disappear, but that is not a valid solution to the problem really (Unless the world would be fine with playing only with a single screen dimension!)

I have also searched Google, but again, I did not find my exact problem. Any insight into what is going on would be great.

Edit to add the rendering code:

```
public void draw() {
    ShapeRenderer renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    renderer.begin(ShapeType.Point);

    for (int i = 0; i < Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); j++) {
            color = (float)gradient.get(j, i);
            renderer.setColor(color, color, color, 1.0f);
            renderer.point(j, i, 0.0f);
        }
    }

    renderer.end();
}
```

Comment: What does your code do to generate the image?

Comment: I added the code used to do the rendering. It is within a new class that handles the generation of worlds and I kind of whipped it together to test the ANL implementation to see if maybe it was just my noise library but that is not the case, haha. Both result in the same thing, those weird black lines. I am not sure if this helps, but the lines are colored the same as the clear color. If i set the clear color to red, the lines are red, for example.

Comment: How is your screen setup?  I suspect the viewport width doesn't quite match the physical width.  I think trying to use a ShapeRender "point" to do per-pixel screen operations is going to lead to trouble, though, as there are a lot of mapping layers in-between.  You might be better off using a Pixmap.

Comment: I will give the Pixmap a try. That is something I was thinking about trying (I have been researching still, haha). Honestly, I did not do much screen setup, I was primarily testing the algorithms I had in place so I left the defaults in place (Set the clear color, clear the screen, and then the drawing code above). The ShapeRenderer "point" is basically just a placeholder to visualize the noise combinations.

Comment: Aha! P.T., you are a genius. Switching to a Pixmap solved all of my problems! I should not have been cutting corners for the testing phase (It is a lesson learned). Turn that into an answer of sorts and I will gladly credit you for the solution provided. :)